# Copy function outside the loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

```js
var input = document.querySelector("#input");
var output = document.querySelector("#output");
"use strict";

(function() {
  output.style.whiteSpace = "pre-wrap";
  var genTimeout;
  input.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    clearTimeout(genTimeout);
    genTimeout = setTimeout(generate, 400);
  });
  input.addEventListener("paste", generate);

  function generate() {
    var text = input.value.trim();

    if (text === "") {
      output.innerHTML = "";
      return;
    }

    var finalText = "";
    finalText += "<div class='copy'>" + applyCharMap(oldEnglishCharMap, text) + "</div>\n";

    finalText += "<div id=\"moreFontsCtn\"></div>";
    finalText += "<button onclick=\"moreFontsCtn.innerHTML += loadMoreFonts('".concat(text, "');prepareCopy()\">load more fonts</button>");
    output.innerHTML = finalText.trim();

    prepareCopy();
  }

  window.loadMoreFonts = function(text) {
    var out = "";
    for (var _i = 0; _i < 2; _i++) {
      var res = void 0;
      if (Math.random() < 0.7) res = wrapInSymbols(crazifyText(text), 2);
      else res = wrapInFlourish(crazifyText(text), 2);
      out += "<div class='copy'>" + res + "</div>\n\n";

    }
    return out;
  };


  var flourishArray = ["★·.·´¯`·.·★ [[text]] ★·.·´¯`·.·★", "▁ ▂ ▄ ▅ ▆ ▇ █ [[text]] █ ▇ ▆ ▅ ▄ ▂ ▁", "°°°·.°·..·°¯°·._.· [[text]] ·._.·°¯°·.·° .·°°°"];

  function wrapInFlourish(text) {
    return flourishArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * flourishArray.length)].replace("[[text]]", text);
  }

  function wrapInSymbols(text, number) {
    return randomSymbols(number) + "  " + text + "  " + randomSymbols(number);
  }

  function applyCharMap(map, text) {
    var out = "";
    var _iteratorNormalCompletion2 = true;
    var _didIteratorError2 = false;
    var _iteratorError2 = undefined;

    try {
      for (var _iterator2 = text.split("")[Symbol.iterator](), _step2; !(_iteratorNormalCompletion2 = (_step2 = _iterator2.next()).done); _iteratorNormalCompletion2 = true) {
        var c = _step2.value;
        if (map[c] !== undefined) out += map[c];
        else if (map[c.toLowerCase()] !== undefined) out += map[c.toLowerCase()];
        else out += c;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      _didIteratorError2 = true;
      _iteratorError2 = err;
    } finally {
      try {
        if (!_iteratorNormalCompletion2 && _iterator2.return != null) {
          _iterator2.return();
        }
      } finally {
        if (_didIteratorError2) {
          throw _iteratorError2;
        }
      }
    }

    return out;
  }

  var oldEnglishCharMap = {
    "a": "",
    "b": "",
    "c": "",
    "d": "",
    "e": "",
    "f": "",
    "g": "",
    "h": "",
    "i": "",
    "j": "",
    "k": "",
    "l": "",
    "m": "",
    "n": "",
    "o": "",
    "p": "",
    "q": "",
    "r": "",
    "s": "",
    "t": "",
    "u": "",
    "v": "",
    "w": "",
    "x": "",
    "y": "",
    "z": "",
    "A": "",
    "B": "",
    "C": "ℭ",
    "D": "",
    "E": "",
    "F": "",
    "G": "",
    "H": "ℌ",
    "I": "ℑ",
    "J": "",
    "K": "",
    "L": "",
    "M": "",
    "N": "",
    "O": "",
    "P": "",
    "Q": "",
    "R": "ℜ",
    "S": "",
    "T": "",
    "U": "",
    "V": "",
    "W": "",
    "X": "",
    "Y": "",
    "Z": "ℨ"
  };

  function crazifyText(text) {
    text = text.split("");

    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      text[i] = crazifyCharacter(text[i]);
    }

    return text.join("");
  }

  function crazifyCharacter(c) {
    c = c.toLowerCase();
    var map = {
      "&": "⅋",
      "%": ["⅍", "℀", "℁", "℆", "℅"],
      "0": ["０", "Ѳ", "ʘ"],
      "1": ["➀", "❶", "１"],
      "2": ["２", "❷", "➁"],
      "3": ["３", "❸", "➂"],
      "4": ["４", "❹", "➃"],
      "5": ["❺", "➄", "５"],
      "6": ["６", "❻", "➅"],
      "7": ["７", "❼", "➆"],
      "8": ["８", "➇", "❽"],
      "9": ["➈", "❾", "９"],
      "<": ["≼", "≺", "＜", "❮", "❰", "⫷"],
      ">": "☽≫≻≽≿⋝⋟⋑⊃⊐⊒⫸》＞❯❱",
      "[": "【〖〘〚［",
      "]": "】〗〙〛］",
      "*": "✨✩✪☆＊",
      "a": ["Ⓐ", "ⓐ", "α", "Ａ", "ᵃ"],
      "b": ["Ⓑ", "ⓑ", "в", "Ｂ", "ᵇ"],
      "c": ["Ⓒ", "ⓒ", "匚", "¢", "ᶜ"],
      "d": ["Ⓓ", "ⓓ", "∂", "Ｄ", "ᵈ"],
      "e": ["Ⓔ", "乇", "ⓔ", "є", "ᵉ"],
      "f": ["Ⓕ", "ⓕ", "ƒ", "Ｆ", "ᶠ"],
      "g": ["Ⓖ", "ⓖ", "ق", "g", "Ꮆ"],
      "h": ["Ⓗ", "卄", "ⓗ", "н", "ʰ"],
      "i": ["Ⓘ", "ⓘ", "ι", "Ｉ", "ᶤ"],
      "j": ["Ⓙ", "ⓙ", "נ", "Ｊ", "ʲ"],
      "k": ["Ⓚ", "ⓚ", "к", "Ｋ", "Ҝ"],
      "l": ["Ⓛ", "ⓛ", "ℓ", "ㄥ", "ˡ"],
      "m": ["Ⓜ", "ⓜ", "м", "Ｍ", "爪"],
      "n": ["Ⓝ", "几", "ⓝ", "η", "ᶰ"],
      "o": ["Ⓞ", "ㄖ", "ⓞ", "σ", "ᵒ"],
      "p": ["Ⓟ", "ⓟ", "ρ", "Ｐ", "ᵖ"],
      "q": ["Ⓠ", "ⓠ", "q", "Ｑ", "ᵠ"],
      "r": ["Ⓡ", "ⓡ", "я", "尺", "ʳ"],
      "s": ["Ⓢ", "ⓢ", "ѕ", "Ｓ", "ˢ"],
      "t": ["Ⓣ", "ⓣ", "т", "Ｔ", "ᵗ"],
      "u": ["Ⓤ", "ⓤ", "υ", "Ｕ", "ᵘ"],
      "v": ["Ⓥ", "ⓥ", "ν", "Ｖ", "ᵛ"],
      "w": ["Ⓦ", "ⓦ", "ω", "Ｗ", "山"],
      "x": ["Ⓧ", "ⓧ", "χ", "Ｘ", "ˣ"],
      "y": ["Ⓨ", "ㄚ", "ⓨ", "у", "ʸ"],
      "z": ["Ⓩ", "ⓩ", "z", "乙", "ᶻ"]
    };

    if (map[c]) {
      return randomElement(map[c]);
    } else {
      return c;
    }
  }

  function randomElement(array) {
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
  }

  function randomSymbols(n) {
    var symbols = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
    var s = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      s.push(randomElement(symbols));
    }

    return s.join("");
  }

  function randInt(min, max) {
    return min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
  }
})();

// copy function here
function prepareCopy() {
  var copy = $("div#output .copy");

  for (const copied of copy) {
    $('div#output').on('click', '.copy', function() {
      document.execCommand("copy");
    });

    copied.addEventListener("copy", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (event.clipboardData) {
        event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", copied.textContent);
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event.clipboardData.getData("text"))
      };
    });
  };

}
```

```css
.box {
  height: 50px;
}

.text {
  height: 254px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea class="box" maxlength="160" rows="12" id="input" placeholder="Enter Your Text Here" value=""></textarea>
  <div class="text" id="output"></div>
</body>
```

Here is the code to generate random text and copy it with on click. User type any word in input and output shows formatted text. User click on text and it will copy in the clipboard. How many times user click on text and it will add in the clipboard. But when user click on load more and click on text it copies text many times to clipboard and increase the numbers in clipboard on every click. It should be copy one in clipboard on every click.